# Using 2 different client to route chat messages using ws and WAMP router

Tags: node.js, websocket, autobahn, crossbar

I am building a chat support application for my company, I am using node js, websocket and WAMP router to do the same, there is 2 different clients (html). One for customers to send request and one for support to respond to the same.

I am confused at the start of the same, how to transfer message between 2 different html clients. If there is any example could someone help me on this.

I have got single html client working fine but not on 2 html client, how to transmit chat messages.

Thanks in advance

Sunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With WAMP on a conceptual level you don't transfer messages between clients, but you send messages to a topic and subscribers to the topic receive these. So your first HTML client publishes to a topic and the second HTML client receives these if its subscribed to this topic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so as I understand this should be a publish subscribe module we should use, and use private chat of websocket to transmit data between clients, probably we need to use a temp anonymous user for the subscriber, and use private message for the temp anonymous user. so the client1.html we need to set as publisher, and client2.html should be subscriber. But any example to help me

Comment: For an example chat application see https://demo.crossbar.io/chat/index.html which has a link to the source code.